# 9 Patch image is drawn with the black pixels, why?

Tags: android, android-imageview, nine-patch

I got a 9 patch image which is the background of some imageview on my project.

however, the image is drawn with the black pixel of the 9-patch tool.

this is not the first time i use 9 patch...but somehow it's not working now.

The image is 100% png, and the extension of the file is ".9.png"

what can cause this?

thanks!

Comment: can you post the original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has happened to me before in a perfect 9-patch image. My advice is, if you are using Eclipse, clean your project (thus regenerating the resource files), uninstall the application and deploy again.

If that doesn't work at first or second try, it's probably a problem concerning the image.